# Trying to understand this count of Servlet calls

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm making some load test using [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) and [Apache benchmarking tool](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html). I count the number of calls for the `Servlet` and for the method `runAlgo` inside `processRequest`.
I use this code :

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    @WebServlet(name = "Servlet", urlPatterns = {"/test"})
    public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

        static int count=0;
        static int count2=0;
        /** 
         * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println("Process request : "+count2++);
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            try {
                // TODO output your page here
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<head>");
                out.println("<title>Result</title>");  
                out.println("</head>");
                out.println("<body>");
                out.println("<h1>Result : " + runAlgo() + "</h1>");
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>");

            } finally {            
                out.close();
            }
        }

        private ArrayList<String> runAlgo() {
            System.out.println("algo : "+count++);
            //the algo code
        }
  }
```

I have 2 problems :

First, the method `runAlgo()` is called more often than `processRequest`, it seems strange because `runAlgo` is only called here!

Then the other problem concern the benchmark, if I send for example 200 requests I have never in the log a count of 200, but the tools said that all transactions had been successful (server responded with a return code < 400)

***Have you some explanations for this comportment?***

I use `apache-tomcat-7.0.11` and `jdk1.7.0_02`

Comment: it's probably in the way you calculate log occurrences

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I'm liking the word "comportment".

Comment: @Qwe, ok any advices? And I found comportment in the dictionnary maybe "behaviour" is better? Sorry for my english :s

Comment: How do you know runAlgo() is called more often?  How did you determine this?

Comment: The count of in `runAlgo` is higher than the one in `processRequest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [volatile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable) keyword because **count** and **count2** are used by a lot of threads

```
 static volatile int count=0;
 static volatile int count2=0;
```

Comment: `volatile int` improve result (almost perfect for runAlgo) but it's still imprecise. `AtomicInteger` works perfectly thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a threading issue. Multiple threads will run the code, and the ++ increment operation is not atomic.